# Cores diferentes dentro da tag h1

Tags: javascript, html, css

Existe alguma forma de aplicar cores diferentes a cada trecho de um texto dentro de:

```
<h1>Cor1 Cor2 Cor3</h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Opção com só uma tag `<h1>` e `background-image:linear-gradient` com 3 cores.

```css
h1 {
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, purple 0%, purple 33%, limegreen 33%, limegreen 66%, blue 66%, blue 100%);
}
```

```html
<h1>G1 G2 G3</h1>
```

**OBS:** Para cada palavra a mais vc tem que ir incluindo as cores dentro do linear-gradiente. Repare que eu só coloquei 3 cores em, `0%-33%, 33%-66%, 66%-100%`. *Para 4 cores e 4 palavras* sera `0%-25%, 25%-50% etc...` *(pode variar as porcentagens dependendo do tamanho das palavras)*

---

Da para fazer com o *seletor adjacente* dessa forma `h1 + h1 + h1 {...}`

Veja o exemplo:

```css
h1 {color: blue; display: inline}
h1 + h1 {color: red}
h1 + h1 + h1 {color: green}
```

```html
<h1>P1 </h1>
<h1>P2 </h1>
<h1>P3 </h1>
```

---

Existem seletores para a **primeira letra** e para a **primeira linha**. Desse forma

```
::first-letter
::first-line
```

Mas para primeira palavra e para última palavra ainda não exite, porém já está no "Road Map" do CSS4, vc pode achar algumas referências sobre isso no Google.

E aqui tem um artigo bem interessante sobre isso: https://css-tricks.com/a-call-for-nth-everything/

Se vc quiser fazer com JavaScript, aqui tem uma opção bem popular http://letteringjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Você pode atribuir classes ao span dentro da h1 e trocar a cor com css.

```css
.color1{
        color: red;
 }
.color2{
         color: black
}
.color3{
        color: blue
}
```

```html
<h1>
         <span class="color1">Cor1</span>
         <span class="color2">Cor2</span>
         <span class="color3">Cor3</span>
    </h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso:

CSS:

```
h1 {
    font-size:22px;
    color:#341C12;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-style:italic;
}
h1 .h1color {
    color:#862E06;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1>News <span class="h1color">&amp; events</span></h1>
```

tirei [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614088/css-two-colors-of-h1)

Answer (score 0):

É só mais uma opção!

```css
.cor1{
   color: red;
}
.cor2{
   color: green;
}
.cor3{
   color: blue;
}

.cor1, .cor2, .cor3 {
   display:inline;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="cor1">Cor1</h1> <h1 class="cor2">Cor2</h1> <h1 class="cor3">Cor3</h1>
```

Comment: mas assim é uma cor para cada `<H1>`

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, pois é, até a resposta aceita foi editada e colocado algo parecido com isso